# React Native app is stuck on splash screen after adding React Navigation using Stack.Screen (iOS/Android)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Like the question says, I was following a tutorial and it was working fine so I wanted to implement it into my own side project app.
After adding it exactly the same as the doc says the component in the <Stack.Screen/> won't load.
I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work. No errors either so I'm stuck on how to debug.

As I don't know which part of my code is causing the problem I will post my github repo link here.

https://github.com/totablue/ToyBoxOfWords

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.
The thing that was causing my app to get stuck on the splashscreen was the SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
that was called while the app was loading the font.

```
    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if (fontsLoaded) {
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [fontsLoaded]);
```

this part of the code was not running so the splash screen never went away.

Used this video to load custom fonts in a different way and it fixed everything.
https://youtu.be/viIkcDYSBrI

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run your code, and it worked well. The problem is that you have  not added some dependencies!

This is the `package.json` file that I use with your code.

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo-font": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "*",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "*",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried replacing the dependencies in my package.json but doesn't seem to work... I was thinking maybe the dependency versions had something to do with it but didn't change anythign..

Comment: You can try: https://snack.expo.dev/@vudanmax/nghich

Comment: Thank you I will compare the two to see what might be causing the problem.

Comment: I ran it on your snack and it seems to be working fine. But I try to run in on my phone and it doesn't work. I think there's an error elsewhere.